# Error when post message from C# program with server using Twisted python

Tags: c#, python, httpwebrequest, twisted

My Method to post a message to server using C# .NET 4.0

```
 private String postHTTP(String url)
    {
        String result = "";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "Data has Posted";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        **request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";**
        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        txtWebServerStatus.Text = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

my server code to provide a form to type and print what you type in form

```
from twisted.web.server import Site   
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.error import NoResource   
import cgi

  class DynamicPage(Resource): 
    def render_GET(self, request):  
        return '<html><body><form method="POST"><input name="the-field" type="text" /></form></body></html>'

    def render_POST(self, request):        
        return '<html><body>You submitted: %s</body></html>' % (cgi.escape(request.args["the-field"][0]),)

root = Resource()   
dynamic = DynamicPage()    
root.putChild("fool", dynamic)
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(7777, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Error on post method:
in line `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();`

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

When I using post method have error on server:

```
C:\Users\sepdau>C:\Python27\python.exe E:\server.py
Unhandled Error Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 1349, in dataReceived  finishCallback(data[contentLength:])

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 1563, in _finishRequestBodyself.allContentReceived()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 1618, in allContentReceived req.requestReceived(command, path, version)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 773, in request Received self.process()

--- <exception caught here> ---

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 132, in process
    self.render(resrc)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 167, in render
    body = resrc.render(self)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\resource.py", line 216, in render
    return m(request)

  **File "E:\server.py", line 25, in render_POST
    return '<html><body>You submitted: %s</body></html>' % (cgi.escape(request.a
rgs["the-field"][0]),)
exceptions.KeyError: 'the-field'**
```

I think error on Server or ContentType I use no correct.
Can you help me.
Thank for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem you're hitting is:

```
KeyError: 'the-field'
```

This is because your client is posting:

```
Data has Posted
```

There are no form fields in that post data.  There are two things you probably want to do.

First, make your server more robust against bad input.  It's already somewhat robust: bad input generates a 500, but the server continues to operate and process future requests.  You might want to generate a more useful error page to help clients figure out what they're doing wrong, though.  So, try handling the KeyError:

```
def render_POST(self, request):        
    try:
        value = request.args["the-field"][0]
    except KeyError:
        value = "<missing the-field value>"
    return '<html><body>You submitted: %s</body></html>' % (cgi.escape(value),)
```

Now your client should get a 200 response, even if it keeps submitting form data without the form field the server is looking for.

Next, fix your client to submit post data that includes the correct form fields.  Try a string like:

```
the-field=%5B%27some+value%27%5D
```

You can generate this in Python using `urllib.urlencode`, eg:

```
urllib.urlencode({'the-field': ['some value']})
```